# Agora in Flutter- disablle one persons's video and make another person's video full screen in the video chat

Tags: android, flutter, agora.io, videochat

I am using [Agora](https://www.agora.io/en/) in a [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) application. It's a very basic app where 2 users can just go online to have a video chat with one another. The source code is pretty small in size and easy to understand as well. But my issue is: I want to show only one person (Person1) in the video and not the other person (Person2).

I have used the [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine) plugin.

**main.dart**:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_local_view.dart' as RtcLocalView;
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_remote_view.dart' as RtcRemoteView;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';


const appId = "...";//Obtain it from Agora site
const token = ""; // Temporary token generated from Agora site

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // int? _remoteUid=1;

  int _remoteUid=1; // for another user remoteUid=2;
  bool _localUserJoined = false;
  late RtcEngine _engine;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }

  Future<void> initAgora() async {
    // retrieve permissions
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    //create the engine
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
    await _engine.enableVideo();
    _engine.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
          print("local user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            _localUserJoined = true;
          });
        },
        userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
          print("remote user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = uid;
          });
        },
        userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
          print("remote user $uid left channel");
          setState(() {
            // _remoteUid = null;
            _remoteUid = 0;
          });
        },
      ),
    );

    // await _engine.joinChannel(token, "test", null, 0);
    await _engine.joinChannel(token, "InstaClass", null, 0);

  }

  // Create UI with local view and remote view
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: _remoteVideo(),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 150,
              child: Center(
                child: _localUserJoined
                    ? RtcLocalView.SurfaceView()
                    : CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Display remote user's video
  Widget _remoteVideo() {
    
    if (_remoteUid != 0) {
      return RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(
        uid: _remoteUid,
        channelId: "InstaClass",
      );
    }else {
      return Text(
        'Please wait for remote user to join',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Same code is used for both Person1 and Person2 with a few changes.** The above code snippet is for Person1 (notice `int remoteUid=1;`). For Person2, I have used `int remoteUid=2;`. For disabling the video of Person2, in Person2's app, I have added the following line

```
_engine.enableLocalVideo(false)
```

after the line:

```
await _engine.enableVideo();
```

Now Person2 sees Person1's video (i.e., remote video) in full screen but does not see his own (Person2)  video (i.e., local video). A black rectangle is shown in the place of the local video.

Q1) How can I hide this black rectangle ? I just want to show only the remote video from Person2's side.

And from person1's side, no video of Person2 is shown and Person1's video is shown in a small rectangle.

Q2) How can I show Person1's video in full screen instead of a small rectangle from his own (Person1) side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove **Align** widget from you code to hide the small screen from your call UI. This will hide the `box` and even if you don't call `_engine.enableLocalVideo(false)` functions local video will not be `visible` and after doing so your both questions should be solved. Try once

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: _remoteVideo(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

For Full screen video of self you can assign `local` video instead of `remote` video to the **Center** widget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: _localUserJoined
                ? RtcLocalView.SurfaceView()
                : CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: May I ask you to take a look at an agora related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822128/agora-io-how-to-renew-the-token-automatically-in-flutter ?