# Agora.io - how to renew the token automatically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, token, agora.io

I am building a mobile application with [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/). I am using [agora](https://www.agora.io/en/) to make the video chat app. A temporary token is obtained from Agora manually and is held in `const token`. But after a certain time ( i.e., 2 days), the token is expired and I need to obtain a new token from Agora website again. I want to renew the token automatically from within the Flutter app. I have got a `tokenPrivilegeWillExpire` callback event from [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/flutter/rtc_channel/RtcChannelEventHandler/tokenPrivilegeWillExpire.html) to be used. The doc says there :

> This callback is triggered 30 seconds before the token expires, to
> remind the app to get a new token.Upon receiving this callback, you
> need to generate a new token on the server and call
> [RtcChannel.renewToken](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/flutter/rtc_channel/RtcChannel/renewToken.html) to pass the new token to the SDK.

I just cannot understand how to use the `renewToken` method inside the `tokenPrivilegeWillExpire` event.

**Q1)** How should I implement the `tokenPrivilegeWillExpire` callback event?

The `tokenPrivilegeWillExpire` event  triggers 30 seconds before the token expires. I tried to understand what the situation will be like if the token is already stale before the video chat begins.
My findings follow below:

This [doc page](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/token_error) says :

> `onRequestToken` (or `onTokenPrivilegeDidExpire` on Web): Occurs when
> the token expires. Upon receiving this callback, generate a new token
> on the server, call joinChannel, and pass the new token to join the
> channel.

Regarding the `onRequestToken()` callback, the Java (not Flutter) doc says [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html) :

> Occurs when the token has expired.
>
> After a token is specified when joining the channel, the token expires
> after a certain period of time, and a new token is required to
> reconnect to the server.
>
> Once you receive this callback, generate a new token on your app
> server, and call [`renewToken`](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#af1428905e5778a9ca209f64592b5bf80) to pass the new token to the SDK.

**Q2)** How can I implement the `onRequestToken` event as well ?

My minimal code snippet follows:

```
    import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';
    
    .....//code omitted
    
    const appId = "01898f62b31d4028beb16eafee844314";
    const token =    "00601898f62b31d4028beb16eafee844314IAAKhlw1zAa6Q6mHUPsXm9M3q/nfY4ZXJLlaag4XhctOnBhhfAYAAAAAEADDRZkOFcnaYQEAAQAVydph";
    
    ............// code omitted
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: LiveSession1to1()));

class LiveSession1to1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LiveSession1to1State createState() => _LiveSession1to1State();
}

class _LiveSession1to1State extends State<LiveSession1to1> {

  late RtcEngine _engine;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {});
    //initAgora();
  }

 Future<void> initAgora() async {    
    RtcEngineContext context = RtcEngineContext(appId);
    _engine = await RtcEngine.createWithContext(context);
    
    _engine.setEventHandler(
          RtcEngineEventHandler(
            joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
          
               // code goes here
            },
            userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
              
              // code goes here
            },
            userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
              
               //code goes here
            },
            tokenPrivilegeWillExpire: (token) async {
              
              //I need to renew token here 
            },
          ),
        );

}
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // Code omitted here
 }
}
```

Comment: Hii @Istiaque do you have any backend server for this app?

Comment: @Diwyansh, no. I am looking for how to  have a backend server for it .

Comment: With out backend you will not be able to change the token. And to develop backend you have to go through Agora's API docs.

Comment: Here is a way to build a token server in Node.js : https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-build-a-token-server-for-agora-applications-using-nodejs/. Trying to find whether there is any solution in PHP.

Comment: It seems there is a way to build a token generating solution in PHP here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/token_server#token-generator-libraries. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: Yes I was just about to share the same page https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/token_server?platform=All%20Platforms